# â�� in my html after purify

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ckeditor, htmlpurifier

I have a database the I am rebuilding the table structure was crap so I'm porting some of the data from one table to another. This data appears to have been copy-pasted from MSO product so as I'm getting the data I clean it up with htmlpurifier and some str_replace in php. Here is the clean function:

```
   function clean_html($html) {
    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $config->set('AutoFormat','RemoveEmpty',true);
    $config->set('HTML','AllowedAttributes','href,src');
    $config->set('HTML','AllowedElements','p,em,strong,a,ul,li,ol,img');
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

    $html = $purifier->purify($html);

    $html = str_replace('&nbsp;',' ',$html);
    $html = str_replace("\r",'',$html);
    $html = str_replace("\n",'',$html);
    $html = str_replace("\t",'',$html);
    $html = str_replace('  ',' ',$html);
    $html = str_replace('<p> </p>','',$html);
    $html = str_replace(chr(160),' ',$html);

    return trim($html);
   }
```

However, when I put the results into my new table and output them to the ckeditor I get those three characters.

I then have a javascript function that is called to remove special characters from the content of the ckeditor too. it doesn't clean it either

```
  function remove_special(str) {
    var rExps=[ /[\xC0-\xC2]/g, /[\xE0-\xE2]/g,
    /[\xC8-\xCA]/g, /[\xE8-\xEB]/g,
    /[\xCC-\xCE]/g, /[\xEC-\xEE]/g,
    /[\xD2-\xD4]/g, /[\xF2-\xF4]/g,
    /[\xD9-\xDB]/g, /[\xF9-\xFB]/g,
    /\xD1/,/\xF1/g,
    "/[\u00a0|\u1680|[\u2000-\u2009]|u200a|\u200b|\u2028|\u2029|\u202f|\u205f|\u3000|\xa0]/g", 
    /\u000b/g,'/[\u180e|\u000c]/g',
    /\u2013/g, /\u2014/g,
    /\xa9/g,/\xae/g,/\xb7/g,/\u2018/g,/\u2019/g,/\u201c/g,/\u201d/g,/\u2026/g];
    var repChar=['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u','N','n',' ','\t','','-','--','(c)','(r)','*',"'","'",'"','"','...'];

    for(var i=0; i<rExps.length; i++) {
        str=str.replace(rExps[i],repChar[i]);
    }

      for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
    charcode = str.charCodeAt(x);
          if ((charcode < 32 || charcode > 126) && charcode !=10 && charcode != 13) {
              str = str.replace(str.charAt(x), "");
          }
      }
      return str;
  }
```

Does anyone know off hand what I need to do to get rid of them. I think they may be some sort of quote.

Comment: What character encoding do you use in your systems (database, output, etc.)?

Comment: in html I have this 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

not sure about the database how do I check/know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character encodings are all out of whack.  â�� is indicative to me of a three-byte UTF-8 encoded character.

Some things you need to discover

- What is was the encoding of the old table?
- What is the encoding of the new table?
- What is the encoding of the page that displays ckeditor?

It looks like [HTMLPurifier's default is UTF-8](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.Encoding) so you really need to be aware of the encoding of your data!

Comment: But why is HTML purifier converting a HTML entity to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue: [php remove/identify this symbol �](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298204/php-remove-identify-this-symbol)

The character � is the [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (U+FFFD)](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf). It is used when there was an error within an UTF code:

```
FFFD � REPLACEMENT CHARACTER

 - used to replace an incoming character whose value 
   is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode
```

In most cases it means that some data is interpreted with an UTF encoding while the data is not encoded with that encoding but a different one.

My problem was pasting text from microsoft office products to html, or into a database. The largest offenders seem to be the emdash and smart quotes.

Comment: The obvious fix would be using UTF-8 over the entire pipeline.

Comment: wouldn't that mean that the input into the original table would have needed to be encoded with UTF-8 to begin with ?