# PHp + space in linux

Tags: php

In my below code I am replacing `.` with a non-breaking space using `&nbsp;`

```
$orginal_startString = str_replace('.','&nbsp;',$startString);
```

This works fine in windows and save in database but in linux it's not woking properl it's replacing `.` with special character  `Â`.

Comment: Please show your code and an example

Comment: My code :                                                         $startString = "Apple...";                          $orginal_startString = str_replace('.','&nbsp;',$startString); In database it is storing with special chracter AppleÂ Â Â

Comment: This sounds more like an encoding problem - where do those dots come from? They are not normal `.` dots, are they?

Comment: Sounds like you've actually replaced with the actual non-breaking space character (rather than the named entity), in addition, it sounds like you've got a character encoding issue, and UTF-8 encoding text is being interpreted as codepage 1252

Comment: yes might be I am usin "latin1_swedish_ci" but i have no issues in my local machine only in server I face this problem.. In server alos they r usin same collation type.. I have no idea how to solve now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want space as text not HTML, Use the hex equivalent 0x20.

`$orginal_startString = str_replace('.',chr(0x20),$startString);`

And check this [HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-a-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)

Comment: I tried hex equivalent 0x20. But in db it's not treating as a space character. for eg After apple if i have 2 spaces, spaces are not stored in db.

Comment: And do you want to keep two spaces or one? you can replace every two dots [..] with one dot [.] till there is no two dots, then replace the space.
and check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515905/a-in-my-html-after-purify

Comment: For each dot I need each space in the db.

Comment: <?
$startString = 'I ate apple....You should eat it too.|.|';
$orginal_startString = str_replace('.',chr(0x20),$startString);
print $orginal_startString;
?>
view the source it's as you want it. can i see the INSERT mysql query, and the database charset/structure.

Comment: I am usin "latin1_swedish_ci" but i have no issues in my local machine only in server I face this problem.. In server alos they r usin same collation type.. I have no idea how to solve now.

Comment: What's the character encoding of the pages?
Add this to the server page HTML
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

Comment: I am using smarty templates: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: sir That has nothing to do with the encoding. check between the `<head>` and `</head>` for the meta charset code, if it's not there just paste  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Thank u sir, I tried this but no luck still in database it store as Â