# money_format() function showing � instead of local currency symbol (pound)

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding

Does anyone have any idea why `money_format()` is showing � instead of pound sign (£).

The function performs fine on my local server, but when I upload it to my remote server if renders incorrectly.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Is the `Content-Type` header different on your local and remote server? Have you changed the charset?

Comment: Did you upload text files as binary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `&pound;`, not £

A full list of characters affected in this way can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: you should be able to use the £ symbol if the encoding is correct (ie UTF-8), but +1 because `&pound;` will work regardless of encoding.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I always use &pound; though. At leat you'll know it'll work wherever you use it that way and it allows me to keep my coding consistent.

Comment: @dotty: entity-encode the output prior to sending it to the browser, either with `htmlentities()` or similar, or even just `str_replace()` or `strtr()`, etc. But I'd consider fixing your charset to UTF-8 as a higher priority.

Comment: try `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');`

Comment: setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8'); Worked for me

Comment: Good stuff. Spudley's right, though, you should look at your page charset encoding to make sure it's correct.

Comment: `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');` fixed it for me. Both my local and remote server were serving the content-type header `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. It wasn't a browser character issue, as the � symbol was also visible when viewing the output in a terminal window (with cURL)

Answer (score 0):

Related: [php remove/identify this symbol �](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298204/php-remove-identify-this-symbol)

Quoted from [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo)

The character � is the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (U+FFFD). It is used when there was an error within an UTF code:

FFFD � REPLACEMENT CHARACTER

used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode