# PHP money_format(); £ sign not GBP

Tags: php, money-format

I cannot work out how to get the currency symbol?

At the moment I am using

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
money_format('%i', 1000);
```

Which give me the output

```
GBP1,000
```

But I want

```
£1,000
```

I have checked out the PHP manual but it isn't that helpful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060008/money-format-showing

Comment: @Tim That just tells you to put &pound; instead of £ but I can actually get £ to display. It just shows GBP in it's place. Thanks though :)

Comment: My machine doesn't even print `GBP`. :o

Comment: @Shiplu Your machine probably has no locale files installed for "en_GB". If it's a Debian distro, you can edit `/etc/locale.gen`.

Comment: @LinusKleen, Its Ubuntu Lucid. Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: Basically, Ubuntu *is* Debian (*ducks*). It's the same approach: edit `/etc/locale.gen` and then execute `localegen` (both as root).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
utf8_encode(money_format('%n', 1000));
```

Comment: This is close I think, I am now getting a diamond with a ? in the middle. I have my charset as utf-8 which is weird :S

Comment: just add utf8_encode(money_format('%n', 1000)); and you will see the symbol... :)

Comment: P.s. you should edit your answer to include the utf8_encode bit :)

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
money_format('%n', 1000);
```

It's similar to the selected solution, however it didn't work for me. Why? The reason is that the locale `en_GB` was not defined in my system, only `en_GB.UTF-8`:

```
$ locale -a | grep "en_GB"
en_GB.utf8
```

In addition, by using the UTF-8 codeset directly, the extra call to `utf8_encode` can be saved.

Comment: Much more flexible than the selected answer, as this stops the need to rewrite functions if using different localitys.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution for those of you, like me, who think PHP's money_format is horrible.

```
$formatted = '£' . number_format( (float) $amount, 2, '.', ',' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but the way I found without using money_format which is now deprecated

```
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'en_GB', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
$formattedAmount = numfmt_format_currency($fmt, 1000, "GBP");
echo $formattedAmount;
```

will show £1,000.00

If you need to remove the .00 from the end then you could use

```
substr(formattedAmount, 0, -3);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the soloutions above worked for me. They were printing an '`A`' before the `£` sign. Instead building on Aidan and Diegos soloutions I have the following:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
echo (money_format('%n', $bagel->Price));
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy solution could be te replace GBP with & pound ; (without the spaces) after the money_format.

Comment: On the php manual they show you can use the $ sign so you must be able to get the £ as you can set your location to GB

Comment: Have you tried using `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');`. It was sugested on the website @tim placed as a comment.

Answer (score -6):

Use str_replace() function is an option.

£ - British Pound - `&pound;` (163)

```
// Search for the GBP in your string (subject) then replace for the symbol code
$search = "GBP";
$replace = "&pound;";
$subject = "GBP";
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

Comment: This only makes sense for displaying it on a HTML page